# Outlook inbox unread count wrong (IMAP)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013, unread-mail

I have multiple IMAP accounts in my Outlook 2013 that are showing unread emails but there are no unread emails in this folder.

The suggested solutions from similar problems with Exchange accounts do not help.

How can I fix the unread count for IMAP account in Outlook 2013?

Answer (score 4):

I am also posting the solution, because I did not find this solution anywhere.

The solution has to do with IMAP flags that might prevent some items from being shown.

Follow these steps:

1. Mark the folder with the wrong unread count
2. Switch to the "View" tab
3. Click "View Settings" (a dialog will open)
4. Click on "Filter..." button (a dialog will open)
5. Switch to "Advanced" tab
6. If you have an entry there that reads like "IMAP-Status ... match ... unmarked", mark it, then use the "Remove" button to remove it
7. Click the "OK" button to close the current dialog
8. Click the "OK" button to close the current dialog
9. The list of emails will now also show flagged emails and most likely, when deleting these, your unread count will be correct again

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me it didn't have to do with the filter. It had to do with the special "Bulk Mail" Yahoo IMAP folder. Because spam (arguably) requires your attention, the count is always as high as the number of messages. So if there are three messages in the folder for instance, regardless of them being unread or read, it will show the count of three.

Answer (score 1):

Close your outlook (not minimize), Log in to your Office 365 account, then Webmail, mark the problematic folders 'unread' messages as read, then Logoff Office 365, restart Outlook and voilá!
I'm using Outlook 2016 32-bit and was the only solution I found.
Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced wrong uread count in Outlook 2013 for many types of accounts and was not be able to solve it completely. All problems were solved after upgrading to Outlook 2016 (including "search not working/incomplete" issues).